# In VueJS, vue-resource doesn't work on localhost with fake json

Tags: vuejs2

I follow a vue login tutorial that uses php in the back.

I want to do it just with a fake json to check if the email and username is the same from the the fake json.

For I don't know what reasons doesn't work.
I get in the console

```
http://localhost:9050/users 404 (Not Found)
```

Script

```
  import VueResource from 'vue-resource'     
  const AuthPlugin = {
    setToken(token) {
      localStorage.setItem('authToken', token);
     }
   }

  const users = {
    email: 'example@example.com',
    password: 'example1234'
  }

  export default {
    name: 'login',
    data() {
       return {
          user: {
             email: '',
             password: ''
          }
       }
    },
    methods: {
      login() {
        this.$http.get("http://localhost:9050/users", this.user)
          .then((response) => {
            this.AuthPlugin.setToken(response.body.token);
            console.log('token', token)
            this.$router.push('/home');
          })
      }
    }
  }
```

HTML

```
<form novalidate> 
           <h3>Log in</h3>
           <div>
              <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="E-mail" required minlength="6" maxlength="100" v-model="user.email">
           </div>

           <div>
              <input type="password" id="password"  placeholder="Password" required minlength="6" maxlength="20" v-model="user.password">
              <p class="caps-lock-alert" style="display:none;"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Caps lock is on <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
           </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: That error means that there isn't anything at `http://localhost:9050/users`, so you probably haven't configured your server correctly

Comment: The port you are using seems odd (9050) the standard is usually 8080. If you have php installed locally you could try running: 'php -S localhost:8080' from your terminal when standing in the same directory as where your files are. At least this works for MacOS and Linux.